# CISCO 2950 Switch VLAN Acccess Control

Tags: cisco, vlan

I was wondering how VLAN access control is set for the CISCO 2950?

I have the following scenario:

4 Switches
9 VLANs

Switch 1:
  VLAN 1,
  VLAN 2,
  VLAN 3,
  VLAN 4,
  VLAN 5

Switch 2:
  VLAN 2,
  VLAN 3,
  VLAN 5,
  VLAN 6,
  VLAN 9

Switch 3:
  VLAN 3,
  VLAN 4,
  VLAN 7,
  VLAN 8

Switch 4:
  VLAN 3,
  VLAN 7,
  VLAN 8,
  VLAN 9

How would I set it up for access control. For example, I would like to have VLAN 3 to be able to access all VLANs, but all other VLANs cannot access VLAN 3 except for VLANs 4 + 5.

UPDATE:
There is also a CISCO 2611 Router connected to a trunked port in one of the switches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have a trunked interface to your router, so I assume you are using a vlan interface. And lets say for example that

- vlan 3 is subnet 3.3.3.0/24
- vlan 4 is subnet 4.4.4.0/24
- vlan 5 is subnet 5.5.5.0/24

You need something like this on your router...

```
access-list 30 permit ip 3.3.3.0 0.0.0.255

access-list 31 permit ip 4.4.4.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 31 permit ip 5.5.5.0 0.0.0.255

interface vlan 3
ip access-group 30 in
ip access-group 31 out
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

The 2950 is primarily a Layer 2 switch. As such, it does not know how to pass traffic between VLANs. You'll need to get a Layer 3 device involved to do routing and access control between VLANs/subnets.

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention, one of the switch has a trunk port and is connected to a router.

Comment: Then you will need to set up routes and ACLs on the router for your desired config.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I read some information online about the ACL, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: I'm not a Cisco expert, so sorry, no can do. You probably ought to either completely re-work this question or ask a new question specifically about setting up ACLs and routes on the 2611.